# AlertDialog appearing twice

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

When `showTimeDialog()` is called, dialog appears twice. When I click 'ok', there is another dialog waiting.

```
public void showTimeDialog(){
    final TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(this);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(20);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(15);

    timeDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Test")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d("Picker", timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":"
                    + timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    Log.d("Picker", "Cancelled!");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).setView(timePicker).show();
}
```

In `onCreate()`, I have:

```
        editText_time.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            showTimeDialog();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvotes or why people aren't at least commenting, but my guess is to also provide the code that's calling `showTimeDialog()`.  Also, explain what you've tried so far in terms of debugging so we can help further.

Comment: 1. Why would you post the code inside the function, when you're saying its being invoked twice? How useful do you think that is?  
2. "Why is this happening" is not useful for other people.

Comment: My bad! Please check now

Comment: Limit the touch event by making sure to showTimeDialog only when MotionEvent value is in UP state

Comment: @eee - thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like in the code you are calling `showTimeDialog()` method you expect it to not return unless dialog is dismissed. If it is so (your question is not complete so I am partially guessing), then this is wrong as dialogs are asynchronous.

**EDIT**

It works fine as your dialog IS fired twice. It's because you are doing this in `onTouch()` then first dialog is started then you touch the screen (as this triggers touch event `ACTION_DOWN`) and then you release the finger which triggers `ACTION_UP`. To avoid this, you may want to add condition to your code, and I'd suggest reacting on `ACTION_UP`, like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        showTimeDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Added the code invoking the `showTimeDialog` method. Please check

Comment: Thanks :) That was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain it's being called only once? Have you done any log output? My guess is that because you are calling the method in `onTouch`, the method is being called more times than you think.

`onTouch(View, MotionEvent)` is not only called when the view is touched. There are a number of times it is called with a single press, and you can check the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) docs to see all of the possible actions which invoke this method.

Probably what is happening is the `showTimeDialog()` method is being opened when `ACTION_DOWN` event occurs, then again when a `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` event occurs because your dialog is now blocking the view. Try changing your `onTouch` method as follows:

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    if (arg1.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        showTimeDialog();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it.